# MultiKeyMap in JSF Datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a MultiKeyMap in the Backing bean and I would like to iterate it over datatable for displaying the keys and their value. I tried as shown below, but doesn't work.

```
<p:dataTable var="entry" value="#{partDetail.multiKeyMap}">
  <h:outputText value="#{entry.key[0]}" />
  <h:outputText value="#{entry.key[1]}" />
  <h:outputText value="#{entry.key[2]}" />
</p:dataTable>
```

Can anyone let me know how can I iterate MultiKeyMap in a dataTable ?

Comment: See if this link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074177/displaying-hashmap-keys-and-values-in-a-primefaces-datatable

Comment: Please add java code(ManagedBean's code).