# Primefaces datatable's p:columns not iterating over Map

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I am having a two level map `Map<String,HashMap<String,String>>` which i need to display using a `<p:dataTable>`. The code of managed bean is as follows:

```
@ManagedBean(name="MyBean")
public class MyBean{
    private Map<String,HashMap<String,String>> twoDimentionalMap;
    public void getMapData(){
       twoDimentionalMap=getDataFromDataStore();
    }

}
```

Now I am using this map in my `view.xhtml` file as follows:

```
<p:dataTable var="entrySet1" value="#{MyBean.twoDimentionalMap.entrySet()}">
    <p:columns var="entrySet2" value="#{entrySet1.getValue()}">
         #{entrySet2.getKey()} - #{entrySet2.getValue()}
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

I also tried using

```
<p:dataTable var="entrySet1" value="#{MyBean.twoDimentionalMap.entrySet()}">
    <p:columns var="entrySet2" value="#{MyBean.twoDimentionalMap.get(entrySet1.getKey()).getValue()}">
         #{entrySet2.getKey()} - #{entrySet2.getValue()}
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

I even tried converting the outer map to a list:

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> twoDimentionalMap;
```

However nothing is displayed on datatable. The execution shows no error but there is nothing displayed on the page.

Kindly suggest if I am doing something wrong or if `<p:columns>` is having any issue handling maps.

Thanks

Comment: You only need to display the key/value for `entrySet2`?

Comment: Yes the actual data is stored in the inner map so I need to display only key/value for `entrySet2`

Comment: Do you need dynamic columns or you just used them as a way to iterate over the map?

Comment: I need dynamic columns. As column names are also defined in database so I don't know column names before hand and thus I can't use static columns. Column names and respective data will be fetched from database at runtime and displayed in datatable.

Comment: In the maps you use what would act as column names? The key of the outer map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since the keys of outer map do not have a meaning, converting the outer map to a list is correct.

but your approach to retrieve column names from xhtml does not seem valid. you need to get them independently from the current iteration variable `entrySet1`, otherwise you add a third dimension to the operation, which data table cannot handle.

we need to assume that all keys are same across the listed maps.

here is the code for xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable var="entrySet1" value="#{testMB.twoDimensionalMap}">
    <p:columns var="keySet2" value="#{testMB.columnNames}">
         #{keySet2} - #{entrySet1[keySet2]}
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

and for the bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestMB implements Serializable {

    private List<HashMap<String,String>> twoDimensionalMap;

    public TestMB()
    {
        getMapData();
    }

    private void getMapData(){
        //twoDimentionalMap=getDataFromDataStore();
        twoDimensionalMap = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        twoDimensionalMap.add(new HashMap<String,String>());
        twoDimensionalMap.get(0).put("key0", "value00");
        twoDimensionalMap.get(0).put("key1", "value01");
        twoDimensionalMap.add(new HashMap<String,String>());
        twoDimensionalMap.get(1).put("key0", "value10");
        twoDimensionalMap.get(1).put("key1", "value11");
    }

    public Set<String> getColumnNames()
    {
        return twoDimensionalMap.size() > 0 ? twoDimensionalMap.get(0).keySet() : new HashSet<String>();
    }

    public List<HashMap<String, String>> getTwoDimensionalMap() {
        return twoDimensionalMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... it worked :) You are correct with your suggestion that I was creating three dimensions. However no error was displayed thus I was not able to figure out the cause. Thanks again for your response :)