# Only values from last pe:fluidGrid iteration of p:dataList are updated in model

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-extensions

In my bean I have a `HashMap<PDIDefinition, List<FluidGridItem>>` which i use in a `<p:dataList>` to dynamicaly generate a form.

First I generate the FluidGridItems and place them in the hashMap:

```
private HashMap<PDIDefinition, List<FluidGridItem>> formItems = new HashMap<>();

private void generateModel() {

    for (PDIDefinition pdid : pdiDefinitions) {
        Fragment f = new Fragment();
        f.setDefinition(pdid.getFragmentDefinition());
        fragments.add(f);
        List<FluidGridItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
        formItems.put(pdid, items);

        //((DynamicField)((FluidGridItem)formItems.get(pdid).get(0)).getData()).label;

        for (FragmentValueDefinition fvd : f.getDefinition().getFragmentValues()) {
            FragmentValue fv = new FragmentValue();
            fv.setFragmentValueDefinition(fvd);
            fv.setFragmentId(f.getInner());
            if (f.getValues() == null) {
                f.setValues(new ArrayList<>());
            }
            f.getValues().add(fv);
            fragmentValues.add(fv); //not required?
            DynamicField df = new DynamicField((fv), items.size());
            fields.add(df);

            if ("String".equals(fvd.getType())) {
                items.add(new FluidGridItem(df, "stringValue"));
            }
            if ("Integer".equals(fvd.getType())) {
                items.add(new FluidGridItem(df, "integerValue"));
            }
            if ("Date".equals(fvd.getType())) {
                items.add(new FluidGridItem(df, "dateValue"));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Then I convert them as stated in [Displaying Hashmap keys and values in a primefaces DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074177/displaying-hashmap-keys-and-values-in-a-primefaces-datatable):

```
public List<Map.Entry<PDIDefinition,List<FluidGridItem>>> getFormItemsForDisplay(){
    Set <Map.Entry<PDIDefinition,List<FluidGridItem>>> s = formItems.entrySet();
    return new ArrayList<>(s);
}
```

Finaly in my view I generate the form using dataList and fluidGrid:

```
<p:dataList var="pdi" value="#{FormGenerator.formItemsForDisplay}" id="all" varStatus="loop" type="none">
        <p:panel id="panel" header="#{pdi.key.getFragmentDefinition().getFragmentName()}" style="margin-bottom:1em; width:100%;">

            <pe:fluidGrid  id="fluidGrid" value="#{pdi.value}" var="data"
                           hGutter="20" vGutter="10" widgetVar="fgwv_#{loop.index}">

                <pe:fluidGridItem type="stringValue"  id="txt_">
                    <div class="dynaFormLabel">
                        <p:outputLabel for="txt" value="#{data.label}"/>
                    </div>
                    <p:inputText id="txt" value="#{data.value}"/>
                </pe:fluidGridItem>
                <pe:fluidGridItem type="integerValue" id="int_">
                    <div class="dynaFormLabel">
                        <p:outputLabel for="int" value="#{data.label}"/>
                    </div>
                    <p:spinner id="int" value="#{data.value}" />
                </pe:fluidGridItem>
                <pe:fluidGridItem type="dateValue" id="cal_">
                    <div class="dynaFormLabel">
                        <p:outputLabel for="cal" value="#{data.label}"/>
                    </div>
                    <p:calendar id="cal" value="#{data.value}" showOn="button"/>
                </pe:fluidGridItem>

            </pe:fluidGrid>

        </p:panel>
    </p:dataList>
```

This results in the form I wish.

[image]

My problem is, that only the values from the last iteration of the dataList are updated on the server (PDF in the image).

Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by replacing

```
<p:dataList var="pdi" value="#{FormGenerator.formItemsForDisplay}" 
    id="all" varStatus="loop" type="none">
```

by

```
<c:forEach var="pdi" items="#{FormGenerator.formItemsForDisplay}"
    id="all" varStatus="loop">
```

Got the Idea from https://zenidas.wordpress.com/recipes/jsf-update-single-entry-in-a-datalist-like-component/