# Using a java.util.Map as h:dataTable value

Tags: jsp, jsf, datatable, hashmap

`Ok so I have a managed bean class called 'UserAdministrationBean' ...`

**Edit**:  The question is not about displaying the contents of a `java.util.map` or `java.util.list` but how to properly designate the managed bean class.

After consulting with a colleague, it was pointed out I failed to properly do so which masked the real problem I throught my question addressed. For that I apologize and offer as an answer the correction I needed and thank the participants for their guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Error is only in XHTML page.

I think datatable use only list type of data structure, you can not use MAP for datatable, better to use List, and form List from MAP, and than use.
This question help you better. In java we have various way to get List of MAP.

[Displaying Hashmap keys and values in a primefaces DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074177/displaying-hashmap-keys-and-values-in-a-primefaces-datatable)

**Edited:** you may need to learn how the name of bean work in XHTML, here if your class name is UserAdministrationBean than userAdministrationBean will be use on XHTML page, by default. if you want you can change the name of bean by help of annotation `@ManagedBean(name = "yourbeanName")`